# Recourse if someone answers your dumb question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question that is getting negative rep as trivial. Within hours of asking the original question, I requested that it be deleted, as someone had already given a (trivial) answer and I no longer could. That request was ignored, and the question continues to accrue negative rep.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Edit: Flagging it to be closed seems like an option, but none of the close reasons seem anywhere near appropriate.

Comment: Not post dumb questions in the future?

Comment: Well it's not to vandalise your question through edits, as [you've done](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24268096/3)

Comment: You can ask the moderators to disassociate the post from your account, and they have a legal obligation to comply per the terms of the Creative Commons license.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I just undid that and came here to post, so clearly I already know that. Thank you.

Comment: @JeremyBanks you should post that as an answer so I can upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: @JanDvorak how does that encourage people to continue to use the site?

Comment: @TimKeating When people post lazy questions that demonstrate a lack of an ability to spend 2 seconds (by your own admission) looking for an answer before posting questions here, what makes you think we *want* to be encouraging?  You did something wrong.  There are consequences to that.  Honestly, losing a couple of imaginary internet points is pretty small as far as consequences go.

Comment: Why don't you just delete the post?

Comment: @Werner He can't; it has an answer with a positive score.

Comment: @Servy fine, but should I continue to accrue negative rep FOR ALL TIME as a consequence? That seems harsh. I am admittedly a casual user of the site, and my little bit of rep is important to me. And if it's just "imaginary internet points," why even have a rep system at all?

Comment: @TimKeating: not attracting attention to your poor questions is a good start. Very few people interested in downvoting will pass by once the question is a few hours old so all you're doing now is prolonging the attention span to it.

Comment: As I noted above, I'm still continuing to get dinged for it a week later. Obviously people are finding it in searches.

Comment: Unless you draw attention to the question yourself (by, say, posting about it on meta) it likely wouldn't have attracted more than just a few votes once it was more than a few days old.  If your rep is important to you *then earn it*.  It is a measure of the quality of your contributions.  Why are you *surprised* that it might go down a bit if you post a very low quality contribution?  If you want it to go up, not down, then *provide quality content*.  If the downvotes are discouraging you from providing more low quality content *then they're doing their job*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have no other recourse, you have the option of flagging your post and asking the moderators to disassociate it from your account. They<sup>1</sup> have a legal obligation to comply per the terms of the Creative Commons license. However, if you repeatedly use this approach to avoid reputation penalties, you might be seen as gaming the system and have your account blocked anyway, so please only do this sparingly.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Well, the legal obligation actually rests on Stack Exchange Inc., but I believe it's typically acted on by moderators.</sub>