# What can I do about downvotes on old questions?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, closed-questions, bad-questions

Ok, here is the situation:

I asked a question on Oct 11 '16 at 18:57 on Stack Overflow.  It was a poor question, I only ever asked 3 or 4 questions.  But it did get 2 answers, so it can't be deleted.

Then today, Apr 7 '18 at 12:30 someone downvotes it.  It's also a question that one would typically not expect someone to find with a random Google search about programming.

What can/should I do?

Comment: People can view your profile browse to your questions if they like upvote don't like downvote.

Comment: I understand that but, questions that are closed should not allow any downvotes as it's pointless.  Especially when they have been closed for well over a year.  It dissuades me from posting questions, because someone could use it as retaliation if they don't like what I say.

Comment: You have 10k rep. You'd have to get *five thousand* downvotes to lose all your rep. That's not going to happen from one or two pissed off users.

Comment: @RobertColumbia - it could happen.  Most people don't like me for some reason.  I'm nice guy, just blunt sometimes...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Tell me one thing what if the user upvoted your question will you still say 'meh why the user upvoted my question it is so old' just saying.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar - Oh It's fine if someone upvotes! Just kidding, of course I would say the same thing. I would rather delete the question but that is not an option.  Also how many questions get up votes when they are closed because they are too broad? Sure there are a few, but that is apples to oranges.  Because the question is already marked by the community as being off topic.  At the very least it should be 'frozen' once it's closed.  You can't add answers, why should you be able to add down/up votes.

Comment: If you have just 4 questions you'd need to anger more than 1000 users to lose 10K rep (such users will rarely downvote answer due to cost). While indeed it is possible... I doubt it will ever happen without someone spending significant effort to organize that. To my knowledge it yet to happen on SO.

Comment: [Possibly useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152920/how-to-permanently-delete-my-question-from-stack-overflow).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you'd need to anger 5000 users to lose 10k rep :)

Comment: You can ask a question on meta about the downvotes to get them reversed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre 4*2*5000 = 40K - I'm not sure why would you need 4x multiplier to get 10K down to 0... It would only take two days to downvote 4 questions (or just one day if doing 3 per person to avoid reversal, also you'd need 1700 people).  And there pretty much no way one can get 30K a day to make the rest of downvotes you suggested to count :)

Comment: @Surgach, not a bad idea actually. With upvotes on this question, ArtisticPhoenix actually goes into net profit against those downvotes. Way to go :).

Comment: The moderators *can* disassociate you from a question if you desire this. Please have a look at [this relevant question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262039/recourse-if-someone-answers-your-dumb-question) for more on this.

Comment: If they downvote only _one_ question, that's a -2. If they downvote multiple of your posts, that's serial voting and will be reversed.

Comment: It makes no sense to complain, and your reputation benefits - overall - from having so much historical information. Yes, old questions ding your reputation sometimes. HOWEVER, they will more often gain you reputation. Any time I see a question with 50+ upvotes on something extremely basic I think, "Wow, what a lucky guy to see that question first, or be on the cutting edge of that language." The reputation system strongly favors what Slashdot once called, "obsessive refreshers."

Comment: I can't find any downvoted question from your profile? You have just three questions with upvotes

Comment: StackOverflow is full of mediocre questions which get polished later. Welcome to the club.

Comment: "questions that are closed should not allow any downvotes as it's pointless" It's not pointless; votes are a community's reflection of the quality and effort of a question. A question's status as closed is a reflection of whether the question is within the scope of the site or not. You can ask great questions that are totally off-topic, and you can ask really crappy questions that are on-topic. Two different functions for two different things. The system also considers them separately for things like automatic question deletion.

Comment: I once got downvoted on a question for no apparent reason.  I asked the unknown person who downvoted me to explain why or upvote me, and 10 minutes later it was fixed.

Comment: They can try to downvote my questions but I get upvotes and accepted answers faster then they can ... so ^v^

Answer (score 30):

Check the question to see if there is anything you can do to improve it. If you can improve it, do so. If you can't, move on.

If you feel really strongly about it, you can post a question on Meta tagged with [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question), but that could (read: probably will) cause further downvotes via the Meta Effect.

Comment: Thanks for your time, there is no way to improve it without changing it wholesale, it was more of a is this possible to do.  There is a reason I didn't point to the specific question.  I thought I saw somewhere that if there were no upvoted answers you could delete the question, but it wont let me.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix unaccept the answer, then delete ...

Comment: @rene - doesn't work, still cant delete it after un-accepting the answer.  it says something like `you cannot delete this answer because others have taken the time to provide an answer`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix If you unaccept the answer it will [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) at 03:00 UTC

Comment: @rene - Thanks! I was not aware of that, I just come on an answer questions when I have some free time.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix You're lucky I didn't *upvote* the answer! :evil: